# What is Neitz and why is it important

Tags: zemanim, halacha

What is Neitz and why is it important?
My inspiration:
http://mekubal.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/at-long-last/#comments

Comment: What is Neitz and why is it important?

Answer (score 4):

*Netz* is a misnomer for *hanetz*, i.e. *hanetz hachama*, sunrise. It's important as the earliest or best time *l'chatchila* to do various *mitzvos*, and as a marker used in computing other *z'manim*.

Comment: In particular, the Gemara (Berachos 9b based on Psalms 72:5) says that the ideal time to start saying the Shemoneh Esrei is at *hanetz*.

Comment: @msh, if a mitzva is a night mitzva, it should be completed by midnight, and MUST be completed by dawn ("alos/amud hashachar"), sunrise is too late. It's the day mitzvas that should ideally be done at sunrise or later, but could in a pinch be done starting at dawn. This raises the interesting question -- if the ideal time for Shemoneh Esrei is at sunrise, doesn't that mean you'd be saying Shema just before sunrise (which is okay but less than ideal)?

Comment: @Shalom, about your last point: Shema is different than most daytime mitzvos, since it depends on ובקומך - בשעה שבני אדם עומדים. People used to start their workday at (or near) sunrise, so naturally they'd have to wake up earlier.

Comment: Which is why an oneis can say "night" shema after amud hashachar until hanetz, even though halachically it is day.  Acc. to some, one may lechatechila say both shema's during this time (others diagree, but only on the basis of tarti d'sasrei).

Comment: In what way is it a misnomer?  Because of the construct state, netz hachama is a perfectly valid phrase.  That phrase is then shortened to netz.  Shkiat hachama is similarly shortened to only its initial word: shkia.

Comment: @ZeevFelsen, I understand the correct term is _hanetz hachama_ rather than _netz hachama_.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen , msh210 : see comments [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12416/759) regarding the correct grammar.