# If it's your minhag to daven Hanetz, do you do so even without a minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minhag, zemanim, priorities

A friend once told me that if one's minhag is to daven with Hanetz (i.e., starting the Amida prayer at sunrise), and if there's no Hanetz minyan nearby, you should still daven Hanetz, even without a minyan.

Does anyone have sources for this? Is this halacha?

Answer (score 9):

This is the psak of [Rabbi Yisrael Meir Kagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisrael_Meir_Kagan) in the [third Biur Halacha on Siman 58](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=176).

Of course when davening alone, it is still advisable to go to a minyan later to hear all the *dvarim shebekdusha* that you missed, like kaddish, kedusha, barchu, and keriyat hatorah.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Ish Masliah (vol. 1 16:2) says if you usually daven with netz and it happens that you don't have a minyan to go to, you are supposed to daven with netz alone. I would also think to say that if there is Keriat HaTorah, you go to the later minyan after davening with netz alone.

Answer (score 1):

Here are additional sources that you can review on the topic that address your question:

1)  שו"ת הרמב"ם סימן קפ

2)  חשוקי חמד בבא מציעא דף פג עמוד ב

3)  שו"ת יביע אומר חלק א - או"ח סימן ד