# Is it better to daven in a Minyan throughout the week or on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, priorities, chol-weekday, tefillah-betzibbur

Imagine someone had two job offers:

1. You would have to live more than walking distance away from Shul. However, you could drive to Shul during the week (let's say that it's too expensive to live within walking distance of that Shul).
2. You live within walking distance of a Shul (let's say a totally different community). You would be able to come to Shul on Shabbos but the job would require one to miss minyan throughout the week.

What is more important, davening in a Minyan throughout the week or on Shabbos?

Comment: For me, this is not theoretical, it is my situation.  Where I work is very very far from a shul, so during the week, I daven at home alone.  On shabbos and yomtif, I stay near the shul.

Comment: I do not have a source and therefore I am commenting instead of answering. One can Daven with Neitz during the week and according to some Shittos it is better or equivalent to Davening with a Minyan. However missing Shul on Shabbos seems to me more severe, as it would take away from the flavor of Shabbos.

Comment: In addition the lack of a nearby Shul means that you are living away from a community. Living in a community should also be part of your concern.

Comment: @GershonGold Mitzad hergesh, yes. I was wondering if there is a source.

Comment: @GeshonGold You've only solved for one of the three Tefillot.  So now it's 12 vs 3 tefillot. There are 5 more Barchus during the week, and many, many more Kaddishes. Plus you maintain an evenly spaced Torah reading so that you almost never go 3 days without hearing the Torah read. There are also 9 more Kedushas during the week. You think solving 5 Tefillah beTzibburs is now the tie breaker?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Mitzad hergesh I would say the opposite! Something that is a part of one's day to day life is much more significant than some extra tunes sung on Shabbat

Comment: @DoubleAA: I guess we disagree. Now we need sources to back us up!

Comment: @DoubleAA But here you have community, Kiddushim, or words of inspiration which could help push one further. Interestingly, most Rabbis push for a non-religious person to come to shul on Shabbos relatively early in their journey. It may be because its easier, but it may be because it helps. However, a source each way would be nice.

Comment: my gut is to say that one should maximize davening with a minyan and not try to make one particular prayer more worthy of tefillah b'tzibbur than any number of others. if you can make it to a minyan 6 out of 7 days, I would think (again, just a get sense) that that is preferable to davening with a minyan 1 out of 7 days. And feel free to throw a l'chaim on a Tuesday morning and give a dvar Torah on Thursday.

Comment: I'm with Double AA on this. You're talking about davening with a minyan 6 times versus 1 time. That alone is a clear choice. To say anything different, you would need to make a case that it is permissible to miss minyan 5 days a week to gain a degree of enjoyment on Shabbos.

Comment: Many are in @Dennis's shoes. There's more than Minyan that you miss if you live close to work but far from Shul.

Answer (score 1):

[Mishna Berura 90:29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=239&hilite=) says that it’s permissible to miss a minyan in order to prevent a loss of money. In your first example where You would have to live more than walking distance away from Shul. However, you could drive to Shul during the week, you would not have this dispensation on Shabbos as on Shabbos you have no loss of money. However in the second example where you live within walking distance of a Shul, and you would be able to come to Shul on Shabbos but the job would require you to miss minyan throughout the week. During the week you can avail yourself to the dispensation that it’s permissible to miss a minyan in order to prevent a loss of money.

Comment: How do you know the mishna berura refers to *menias revach* and not just *davar haaveid*?

Comment: You can make the exact opposite case on the basis that if you live more than 18 minutes from a minyan you are not obligated to Daven with them (don't know the source off hand). And then you're comparing missing 1x vs 6x.

Comment: In the first case, your "Shabbos dispensation" is that you live too far away (let's say you can drive to a minyan 10 miles away, but can't walk there or afford to live there)

Comment: Your answer is predicated that "loss of money" is matir, not doche.

Answer (score 0):

The ביאור הלכה says that it permissible to pray with הנץ החמה even without a Minyan.  See below for the quote.  Other positions hold in fact that it may even be preferable to pray at הנץ החמה without a Minyan then to wait later to pray with a Minyan. (See Teshuvot below.)  So following Gershon Gold’s suggestion to address the morning issue, you could pray during the week with sunrise even without a Minyan.  Then on Shabbos you could pray with a Minyan.  This way you could hear Krias Hatorah and pray the Musaf together with a Minyan.  It should be noted that Gershon's suggestion would only address the issue of the morning prayers, and not afternoon or evening prayers.

ביאור הלכה סימן נח

ומצוה מן המובחר וכו' – דע דהזהירים לקרות כוותיקין מותר לקרות ולהתפלל ביחידי אם אין להם מנין וגדולה מזה מוכח במשנה ברכות דף כ"ב ירד לטבול וכו' עיי"ש דאפילו אם אין לו תפילין בעת ההיא ג"כ אפ"ה יזהר לקרותה בזמנה סמוך להנץ ומשנה זו איירי בוותיקין כדמסקינן בגמ' שם:

Additional sources:

1)  שו"ת הרמב"ם סימן קפ

2)  חשוקי חמד בבא מציעא דף פג עמוד ב

3)  שו"ת יביע אומר חלק א - או"ח סימן ד

Comment: What happened to Mincha and Maariv???

Comment: (related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12416/759 )

Comment: @DoubleAA   aggh!  In my haste to write this I had only considered that he was asking about the morning.  You are correct.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for pointing out the related question.  I added the sources over there for anyone who wants to explore them.