# If the only Minyan that is available will pray later in the morning, is it preferable to pray alone with Hanetz or later with the Minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer

[The Shulchan Aruch: Orach Chaim: Siman 89](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=233&hilite=) says that the ideal time to pray Sh'moneh Esrei is at Hanetz hachamah.

If the only Minyan that is available will pray later in the morning, is it preferable to pray alone with Hanetz or later with the Minyan?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.

If you always daven with the sunrise, then - as has been pointed out in the comments - and discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12416/if-its-your-minhag-to-daven-hanetz-do-you-do-so-even-without-a-minyan), you should daven with the sunrise even without a Minyan.

If you're not in the habit of davening at sunrise, then the Shulchan Aruch paskens in the next [Siman (90:9)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=240) that you should always pray with a Minyan.

However, the Siman continues (90:10), if the only available Minyan is going to miss "Sof Zman" and pray *too late* then one should pray ahead of them. (If possible, at sunrise, obviously, since that's the correct time to daven.)